# Spark Dataframe to Tensorflow Dataset (tf.data API)

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to convert aspark dataframe into a tensorflow record, and then call it from tensorflow as a dataset in order to obtain an input for my model. This is not working.

My attempt is as follows:

1) Get a sparksession with the jar of the library spark-tensorflow-connector:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf().set("spark.jars", "path/to/spark-tensorflow-connector_2.11-1.6.0.jar").getOrCreate()
```

2) Save the dataframe as a TFRecord (I take here a dataset as an example):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 120), (2, 130), (2, 140)], ['A', 'B'])

path='path/example.tfrecord'
df.write.format("tfrecords").mode("overwrite").option("recordType", "Example").save(path)
```

3) Load the tfrecord files into the tf.data API (I just take 'A' as a feature for simplicity):

```
path2 = "path/example.tfrecord/*"
dataset=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tf.compat.v1.gfile.Glob(path2))

def parse_func(buff):
       features = {'A': tf.compat.v1.FixedLenFeature(shape=[5], dtype=tf.int64)}
       tensor_dict = tf.compat.v1.parse_single_example(buff, features)
       return tensor_dict['A']

train_dataset = dataset.map(parse_func).batch(1)
```

But when I try to print the dataset iterator:

```
for x in train_dataset:
       print(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
2020-05-21 06:43:53.579843: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:941 : Data loss: corrupted record at 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 1897, in execution_mode
2020-05-21 06:43:53.580090: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at example_parsing_ops.cc:93 : Invalid argument: Key: A.  Can't parse serialized Example.
2020-05-21 06:43:53.580567: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at example_parsing_ops.cc:93 : Invalid argument: Key: A.  Can't parse serialized Example.
    yield
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 659, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2479, in iterator_get_next_sync
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 6606, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: corrupted record at 0 [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/194/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 141, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 148, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 204, in loadTestsFromName
    test = obj()
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/tests/python/output/test_output.py", line 75, in test_TFRecord_new
    for x in train_dataset:
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 630, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 674, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 665, in _next_internal
    return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 1900, in execution_mode
    executor_new.wait()
  File "/home/patrizio/PycharmProjects/pyspark-config/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/executor.py", line 67, in wait
    pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: corrupted record at 0
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is still relevant.

Your glob expression is incorrect. Spark must haved created a _SUCCESS file upon saving the examples to TFRecord. Include the extension in the patters

```py
path2 = "path/example.tfrecord/*.tfrecord"
```

You can also check the list of files python is going to read by simply evaluating

```py
tf.io.gfile.glob(path)
```

I would use this API rather the old `compat.v1`.

The shape of the `tf.io.FixedLenFeature` is also wrong. Each value is a scalar, not a vector of length 5. The correct shape is simply `[]`.

```py
def parse_func(buff):
    features = {'A': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64)}
    tensor_dict = tf.io.parse_single_example(buff, features)
    return tensor_dict

train_dataset = dataset.map(parse_func).batch(3)
```

If you really want to get fancy, using `tf.io.parse_example` is better since it performs vectorised parsing. However, you need to batch before parsing.

```py
def parse_func(buff):
    features = {'A': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64)}
    tensor_dict = tf.io.parse_example(buff, features)
    return tensor_dict

train_dataset = dataset.batch(3).map(parse_func)
```

> One might see performance advantages by batching Example protos with parse_example instead of using this function directly. ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example))

Comment: Hi, if I write to tfrecords like this, I don't get a file extension. So only part-r-00001, etc. Any ideas why this is happening? It is a bit annoying because there also exists a .part-r-00001.src file....